# MySQL Query with two conditional inline SELECT's

Tags: mysql

**The goal:**

- There are two tables, a table of alumni and a table of contributions - each contribution is related by the alumni's ID
- Get a list of alumni who have
  contributed 2-3000 within the date
  range of 2002-10-10 and 2003-10-10.
- Result needs to show alumni's name, ID, each alumni's total given for all-time, and each alumni's total given for the
  specified date range

**The attempt:**

```
SELECT alumni.alumni_id, alumni.alumni_name,
(SELECT SUM(contributed_amt) FROM contribution WHERE contribution.alumni_id = alumni.alumni_id) AS contrib_alltime_total,
(SELECT SUM(contributed_amt) FROM contribution WHERE contribution.alumni_id = alumni.alumni_id AND contribution.date >= 2002-10-10 AND contribution.date <= 2003-10-10) AS contrib_range_total

FROM alumni
WHERE hold_code IS NULL    
ORDER BY lname ASC    
HAVING contrib_range_total >= 2000
HAVING contrib_range_total <= 3000
```

I am getting a syntax error, most likely because I am trying to use two HAVING's

I also realize that you want to use a HAVING with GROUP BY, but I don't need to do any grouping

I probably could do it this way, but I think its inefficient and could take a long time

```
SELECT alumni.alumni_id, alumni.alumni_name,
(SELECT SUM(contributed_amt) FROM contribution WHERE contribution.alumni_id = alumni.alumni_id) AS contrib_alltime_total,
(SELECT SUM(contributed_amt) FROM contribution WHERE contribution.alumni_id = alumni.alumni_id AND contribution.date >= 2002-10-10 AND contribution.date <= 2003-10-10) AS contrib_range_total

FROM alumni

WHERE hold_code IS NULL
AND (SELECT SUM(contributed_amt) FROM contribution WHERE contribution.alumni_id = alumni.alumni_id AND contribution.date >= 2002-10-10 AND contribution.date <= 2003-10-10) >= 2000
AND (SELECT SUM(contributed_amt) FROM contribution WHERE contribution.alumni_id = alumni.alumni_id AND contribution.date >= 2002-10-10 AND contribution.date <= 2003-10-10) <= 3000

ORDER BY lname ASC
```

What would be the fastest and most effective way of achieving this? Any advice is welcome, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.alumni_id,
sum(c.contributed_amt) AS contrib_alltime_total,
sum(case when c.contribution_date BETWEEN '2002-10-10' AND '2003-10-10' then c.contributed_amt else 0 end) AS contrib_range_total
FROM alumni a
INNER JOIN contribution c ON c.alumni_id = a.alumni_id
WHERE a.hold_code IS NULL
GROUP BY a.alumni_id
HAVING contrib_range_total BETWEEN 2000 AND 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.alumni_id, a.alumni_name, 
SUM(c.contributed_amt) AS contrib_alltime_total, 
SUM(c.contributed_amt) AS contrib_range_total

FROM alumni a, contribution c

WHERE a.hold_code IS NULL
AND c.alumni_id = a.alumni_id AND c.date BETWEEN '2002-10-10' AND '2003-10-10'
AND contrib_range_total BETWEEN 2000 AND 3000
ORDER BY lname ASC
```

Comment: Your suggestion didn't quite work so I modified it, but I'm getting an error "Invalid use of group function"

SELECT a.alumni_id,
(SELECT SUM(contributed_amt) FROM contribution WHERE contribution.alumni_id = a.alumni_id) AS contrib_alltime_total,
SUM(c.contributed_amt) AS contrib_range_total

FROM alumni a, contribution c

WHERE a.hold_code IS NULL
AND c.alumni_id = a.alumni_id
AND c.contribution_date BETWEEN '2002-10-10' AND '2003-10-10'
AND SUM(c.contributed_amt) BETWEEN 2000 AND 3000

GROUP BY a.alumni_id
ORDER BY a.lname ASC

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY`, also, use `AND` to join multiple `HAVING` cases...

```
GROUP BY contrib_range_total HAVING contrib_range_total >= 2000 AND contrib_range_total <= 3000
```